# Invoice Increment ID Change

Tags: invoice, magento-2.2.5, increment-id, sales-invoice

I am trying to change my Invoice increment ID through MYSQL table
Current Invoice ID is `000000002`, I want to start next invoice Id from `200000001` So want to add "2" at the start of invoice ID,

When I am trying to change in the MySQL table  **sequence_invoice_1** it's showing me an error: "can't copy the table to the same one"

So can anyone Suggest me, what is the correct way to change increment id of Invoice!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to click the **Go** button from **Table Options** instead of **Copy table to(database.table)** that's why you are getting that error.